# How can I export baked fluid simulations that work in Xcode?

Tags: animation, export, baking, fluid-simulation, alembic

When I export a baked fluid sim to Alembic, it imports back into Blender just fine, but in Xcode, it's just a static mesh.

I've tried a few dozen different combos of bake and export options, and they all seem to work fine for Blender but not Xcode.  The coder for this iOS app downloaded random Alembic files that use a Mesh Sequence Cach Modifier just like my file and they played back their animation inside Xcode with no issues.

We did notice that it seems like the animation node needs to have an empty parent node, but even after doing that we still just got a static mesh.

So we're at a loss.  I've spent the past ~10 hours looking back and forth in Blender at the random Alembic file that works and my simulation that doesn't and I can't find a difference that would matter to Xcode.  Only that the random Alembic tends to make Blender crash if I poke at it too much.

We're not dead set on using Alembic, we just want a solution that gets the animated fluid into the iOS app.

Comment: I'm new to posting on SE, so I'm not sure if this is allowed to share. If you are experienced with using Blender ➡ Alembic (or whatever works) ➡ Xcode, my partner has offered a [job on Upwork](https://www.upwork.com/job/Need-Blender-Guru-Export-Fluids-for-Xcode_~01df52e0f81055caa) to get paid for your expertise and create a training video for us to get this working ASAP.

Of course, the answer would be shared here too in case others need to know.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Alembic files originally thought to be moving in Xcode weren’t using the mesh stream as thought before. I don’t have a Mac, so I couldn’t actually see the result. My partner saw the object translating in Xcode and thought it was working, but the mesh stream I was seeing in Blender was not actually running in Xcode.

This means that we have no working example files of a mesh stream playing from an Alembic file in Xcode.

We’re going to move away from Alembic and give OBJ streaming a shot.